# Bizarre Spark/Scala XML error?

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark

I'm loading an XML file from S3 with this command:

```
val metadata = XML.loadString(sc.textFile("s3://mybucket/metadata.xml").fold("")((s1, s2) => s1 + "" + s2))
```

The first time I run the command, it fails with exception:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 39; The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
```

The second time I run the command, it works!  What gives?

Here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Sample XML file generated by XMLSpy v2015 rel. 3 (x64)     (http://www.altova.com)-->
<session xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="KioskAnalyticsSchemaPromoCodesArray.xsd">
  <kioskID>String</kioskID>
  <sessionId>String</sessionId>
  <sessionStart>String</sessionStart>
  <promoCodes>
    <promoCode code="String" valid="String" value="String" serverFailureReason="String" online="String"/>
    <promoCode code="String" valid="String" value="String" serverFailureReason="String" online="String"/>
  </promoCodes>
</session>
```

Comment: this error also occurs, not sure if its related: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InputSplitWithLocationInfo